# What is the difference between AsXXX and ToXXX in MongoDb.Bson (official) internally

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm just wondering how the AsXXX and ToXXX operations work in MongoDb. For example,  I have operations like the ones below

```
var person = new BsonDocument();
person.Add("age", 32);
BsonValue age= person["age"];

Console.WriteLine(age.AsBoolean); //throws an exception
Console.WriteLine(age.ToBoolean());  //True
```

The `AsBoolean()` throws an exception, specifically:

> *System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonInt32' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'*

Whereas `ToBoolean()` returns true.

So my question is when to use one than the other? How do they work internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the type of conversion.

AsXXX (somewhat like `as` in C#) is simply a cast. It tries to cast the base `BsonValue` to the XXX Type and. If the instance is in fact of the right type the conversion works. If not, you'll get an `InvalidCastException` as you did.

ToXXX isn't a cast but a conversion. It contains some logic on how to convert from one `BsonValue` to the another and shouldn't throw an exception unless the conversion failed.

In your example the `age` is a `BsonInt32` so `AsBoolean` fails as it tries to cast it to `BsonBoolean` but all `ToBoolean` does is return `false` if the value is `0` and `true` otherwise so it can't fail.